# How to redirect to another component by setting up props from this component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a simple login application by applying some of my own logic. The authentication was successful and I need to redirect to another component after login and I need to take name from the login component to my home component so that I can display as "Welcome -name-" in that component

I tried passing props to the  and it didn't work

This is my Login.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    // import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';
    import { Link, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
    import './Login.css';       
    import Home from '../Home/Home'


    class Login extends Component {     
        state = {
            email: null,
            password: null,
            status: null,
            name: null
        }       
        submitHandler = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state);
            axios.get("http://localhost:5000/login/" + this.state.email + "/" + this.state.password).then((res) => {
                this.setState({ status: res.status, name: res.data.name });
                console.log(this.state);        
            });     
        }       
        changeHandler = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const { name, value } = event.target;
            this.setState({ [name]: value });
        }       
        render() {
            const home = <Home />
            return (<div className="wrapper">
                <div className="form-wrapper">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler} noValidate>
                        <div className="email">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" noValidate onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="password">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" noValidate onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="login">
                            <button type="submit">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {((this.state.status) && this.state.status === 200) ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : null}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>);
        }

    }

    export default Login;
```

This is my Home.js:

```
    import React from 'react';

    const Home = (props)=>{
        return(<h1>Welcome {props.name}</h1>);
    }
    export default Home;
```

All I need is to display the output in Home.js as "Welcome -name-" on successful form submission. But, the name is in the state of Login.js. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: You can use react-router-dom. Just send a param with the value you wanted when do routing to Home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options for this issue but I noticed you are using `react-router-dom` so you can do one of the following:

- Pass the username as a parameter of url:

  ```
  <Route path="/home/:username" component={Home} />;
  const Home = (props)=>{
    return(<h1>Welcome {props.match.params.username}</h1>);
  }
  ```

and redirect like this:

```
<Redirect to="/home/john-doe" />
```

- Use `redux` to store your variables in a global store and access them from anywhere.

constants.js:

```
export const SET_USERNAME = 'SET_USERNAME'
```

action.js:

```
import {SET_USERNAME} from './constants'
export function setUsername(payload) {
  return {
    type: SET_USERNAME,
    payload,
  };
}
```

reducer.js:

```
import {
  SET_USERNAME,
} from './constants';

export const initialState = {
  username: '',
};

export function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USERNAME:
      return { ...state, username: action.payload }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Login.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
// import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';
import {Link, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {setUsername} from './actions'
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import './Login.css';
import Home from '../Home/Home'


class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    email: null,
    password: null,
    status: null,
    name: null
  }
  submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/login/" + this.state.email + "/" + this.state.password).then((res) => {
      this.setState({status: res.status, name: res.data.name});
      this.props.setUsername(res.data.name) // Here you set the username in your redux store
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }
  changeHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {name, value} = event.target;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }

  render() {
    const home = <Home/>
    return (<div className="wrapper">
      <div className="form-wrapper">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler} noValidate>
          <div className="email">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" noValidate onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
          </div>
          <div className="password">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" noValidate onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
          </div>
          <div className="login">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            {((this.state.status) && this.state.status === 200) ? <Redirect to="/home"/> : null}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }

}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    setUsername: username => dispatch(setUsername(username)),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default withConnect(Login);
```

Home.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class Home extends Component{
  render(){
    const {username} = this.props;
    return(<h1>`Welcome ${username}`</h1>);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { username } = state.user;
  return { username };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps);

export default withConnect(Home);
```

- Use cookies to store username of logged in user.

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('username', username);
```

Actually there might be multiple other solutions but these are the things that came to my mind. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank You so much. The first solution really helped. I don't have any knowledge regarding redux. Have to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the problem. When placing js objects or elements, etc. into a string, you need to specify the you will be adding an object by wrapping the string in back quotes. Try wrapping your text in the  tag in back quotes, and prefix your js object (the props your passing in) with a dollar sign. This lets React know that the string will also contain js, rather than just a text string. In your case you may also need the "this" bind like so:

```
<h1>`Welcome, ${this.props.name}`</h1>
```

I'm not entirely sure how to explain "this", maybe someone else can clarify further. Below is the code change in context of your Home.js file.

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = (props)=>{
    return(<h1>`Welcome ${props.name}`</h1>);
}
export default Home;
```

I hope this helps! Good luck with your app :)

Comment: Hello, thank You so much for the response and for the wishes. Unfortunately that didn't help. In short I am in a need to take the name which is in the state of my Login.js component and pass it as a prop to my Home.js component. It was working without routing. But, I am unable to do with routing and I need to do it as when this.state.response === 200 which is a sign I set for successful login

Answer (score 0):

There are few options to you.

1. You can pas it via query string. but its not accessible through
   props.
2. If you have set up state management library like Redux, you
   can set the store with the logged person details, and then connect
   home page to that specific section of redux store. Then you can access it via props.
3. Store logged user details in browser local storage (You may want more details of 
   logged in user than just the name going forward). I think for this type
   of functionality this is the best solution. Not via props passing. Then those information are easily and readily available in anywhere in your application.

Cheers,